# Script does not work after the first time pressing the gui button

Tags: roblox

this script does not work after i press the gui button the first time

```
local debounce = true
local player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
local target = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("ClubTeleport")
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    if debounce == true then
        debounce = false
        player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = target.CFrame*CFrame.new(0,3,0)
    end
end)
```

please help

i was expecting it to work after first click

Answer (score 0):

The point of a `debounce` flag is to block multiple interactions from happening before the first finishes. But, the important thing to do is to reset the flag back to its original state once the work is done.

You have set the flag, but never reset it.

```lua
    if debounce == true then
        debounce = false
        player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = target.CFrame*CFrame.new(0,3,0)
        debounce = true
    end
```

Technically, you don't need this debounce at all. Moving the Humanoid doesn't yield the code, so there isn't a risk that the user would be able to click the button multiple times before the object moved.